# correct way to rename user and remove password with ec2 user-data

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, centos7, amazon-ami

I have a centos7 base ami and have successfully changed the user name using the ec2-launch user data modified from an amazon-linux script

```
#!/bin/bash
groupadd ec2-user
usermod -d /home/ec2-user -m -g ec2-user -l ec2-user centos
echo ""  | sudo tee -a  /etc/sudoers
echo "Defaults:root !requiretty"  | sudo tee -a  /etc/sudoers
echo "ec2-user   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL"  | sudo tee -a  /etc/sudoers
echo "Defaults:ec2-user !requiretty"  | sudo tee -a  /etc/sudoers
```

log in works as expected and home directory has been changed, however when I use sudo it still asks for a password. As I cannot get into the file to check format I wonder if I am using the correct syntax?

How do change the user and remove the sudo password requirement in a single script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your Cloudinit userdata script is failing because it's attempting to use `sudo` without a tty (and the `!requiretty` hasn't been added yet). Since that script runs as root anyways, this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
groupadd ec2-user
usermod -d /home/ec2-user -m -g ec2-user -l ec2-user centos
echo ""  | tee -a  /etc/sudoers
echo "Defaults:root !requiretty"  | tee -a  /etc/sudoers
echo "ec2-user   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL"  | tee -a  /etc/sudoers
echo "Defaults:ec2-user !requiretty"  | tee -a  /etc/sudoers
```